# pandas AND filtering

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I thought "&" means AND, but in below example it acts like OR, because this should give back row at index=1.
I want rows where column "e" is NOT 1 AND column "g" is NOT "a" simultaneously, but here it's basically an OR because it gives back no rows. How would you implement the AND?

```
ex=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,"a"],[1,2,"b"]], columns=['e','f','g'])
ex[(ex.e!=1) & (ex.g!="a")]
```

[image]

Edit: doesn't work with "and"
[image]

Comment: You are doing bitwise and.  You want logical and: `ex[(ex.e!=1) and (ex.g!="a")]`

Comment: doesnt work @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `~` in the front , this will only exclude the row with e=1 and g = a

```
out = ex[~((ex.e==1) & (ex.g=="a"))]
print(out)
   e  f  g
1  1  2  b
```

Comment: hi, this gives back both rows

Comment: @Chris assign it back to a new dataframe